# what is the relation between actual pixels and html(css) pixels in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, browser

I am implementing one phonegap application. Here everything going fine but when I am talking device specifications like:

> 1)BlackBerry Bold Touch 9900 Screen specifications are as following

```
Body    Dimensions  115 x 66 x 10.5 mm (4.53 x 2.60 x 0.41 in)
Weight              130 g (4.59 oz)
Keyboard QWERTY     Display     Type    TFT capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors
Size               640 x 480 pixels, 2.8 inches (~286 ppi pixel density)
```

But when I  test following function in java script:

```
function findScreenSize()
{
    alert("width:"+window.innerWidth +"Height:"+ window.innerHeight);   
}
```

> It displaying SIZE width : 356 Height : 267 (356 x 267)
>
> 2)BlackBerry Bold Touch 9930 Screen specifications are as following

```
Body Dimensions     115 x 66 x 10.5 mm (4.53 x 2.60 x 0.41 in)
Weight          130 g (4.59 oz)
Keyboard QWERTY     - Touch-sensitive controls
Display     Type        TFT capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors
Size                640 x 480 pixels, 2.8 inches (~286 ppi pixel density)
```

Then I run same javaScript function I got following output:

> it displaying SIZE width : 417 Height : 313 (417 x 313)

Why it is behaving like this ?

Can anybody know relation between core pixel and HTML pixel please give answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution that

previously i am using following meta tag (add '<' starting of following two meta tags)

**meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">**

But now i am using

**meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,target-densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0">**

now it is showing same

Comment: "target-densitydpi=device-dpi" is supported from >7.0 versions. This link may help to Others: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/26991/Supported_meta_tag_values_1457801_11.jsp and also this one:  http://blackberry.github.com/WebWorks-Samples/kitchenSink/html/browser/viewport/viewport.html